# Output list of links grouped by extension or base URL - built on regex using python.

Tags: python, regex, grouping

Working on this assignment for a while now. The regex is not particularly difficult, but I don't quite follow how to get the output they want

*Your program should:*

- Read the html of a webpage (which has been stored as textfile);
- Extract all the domains referred to and list all the full http addresses related to these domains;
- Extract all the resource types referred to and list all the full http * addresses related to these resource types.

*Please solve the task using regular expressions and re functions/methods. I suggest using ‘finditer’ and ‘groups’ (there might be other possibilities). Please do not use string functions where re is better suited."*

**The output is supposed to look like this**

```
www.fairfaxmedia.co.nz
    http://www.fairfaxmedia.co.nz
www.essentialmums.co.nz
    http://www.essentialmums.co.nz/
    http://www.essentialmums.co.nz/
    http://www.essentialmums.co.nz/
www.nzfishingnews.co.nz
    http://www.nzfishingnews.co.nz/
www.nzlifeandleisure.co.nz
    http://www.nzlifeandleisure.co.nz/
www.weatherzone.co.nz
    http://www.weatherzone.co.nz/
www.azdirect.co.nz
    http://www.azdirect.co.nz/
i.stuff.co.nz
    http://i.stuff.co.nz/
ico
    http://static.stuff.co.nz/781/3251781.ico
zip
     http://static2.stuff.co.nz/1392867595/static/jwplayer/skin/Modieus.zip
mp4
    http://file2.stuff.co.nz/1394587586/272/9819272.mp4
```

I really need help with how to filter stuff out so the output shows up like that?

Answer (score 0):

1. create list of tuples (keyword, url)
2. sort it according to keyword
3. using `itertools.groupby` group per keyword
4. for each keyword, print keyword and then all urls (these to be printed indentend).